# SQL Server Import/Export wizard login timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Both Source and destination servers are SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit with SP3 on Windows server 2008 R2. I can successfully connect to both of them remotely using SSMS with SQL Server login that has db_owner permission on a custom database. But when I do import or export from one server to another using Import/Export wizard I get the following error related to destination server:

```
Login timeout expired
 A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
 Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)
```

**Update**
Both the named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled on both the servers.

Comment: In the SQL Server Configuration Manger for both instances, is named pipes and TCP/IP enabled?

Comment: @MikeZalansky On one server I'm unable to open the Configuration Manager. I'm getting the following error: `Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager.
Invalid namespace [0x8004010]

Comment: @MikeZalansky I was able to access Configuration Manager using this [MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013). And yes, TCP/IP was enabled on both the servers. I had to enable named pipes. But still no luck.

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Server Service?

Comment: @MikeZalansky Yes, I did restart the services on both the servers.

Comment: Are they on the same domain?

Comment: @MikeZalansky Yes, they are on the same domain.

Comment: Without being there to help troubleshoot, came across this Microsoft doc on troubleshooting this error.  You may find one of the causes listed being your issue.  If you get it fixed, I would be interested in knowing what the cause was.  Hope this helps!  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190181(v=sql.105).aspx